# Does any country "filter" otherwise eligible political candidates?

Tags: election, political-theory, political-system, brazil

In Brazil, almost anyone can enter politics as long as they meet these conditions:

1. must have Brazilian nationality or be naturalized;
2. be in full exercise of political rights;
3. be listed in the Electoral Court;
4. having an electoral domicile in the constituency at least one year
   before the election and being affiliated to a political party at
   least one year before the election.
5. Minimum Age: 18

It is very common for our population to elect [joke candidates](https://edition.cnn.com/2014/10/02/world/americas/brazil-election-wacky-candidates/index.html), which, in general, may not contribute so much as other people. For example, [Tiririca](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tiririca), an illiterate comedian, got elected in 2010 and so far only approved one law project (out of 57), which is a complement to an existing culture project.

Also, in Brazil we can elect people with any criminal history/records, and those names usually are involved in corruption once they are elected.

Is there a country that has a "filtering" system to allow only more "prepared" candidates to be elected, e.g. one that would prevent satirical candidates from being in the election?

If so, what were the results of implementing the system?

Comment: What if the general population in some area is illiterate, for example? Shouldn't they be fairly represented?

Comment: Hong Kong is an example. The main result is that whoever controls the filtering rules rules.

Comment: Most systems have a number of signatures and a deposit required. I think it's totally valid for the public to elect whoever they wa as long as it's not under false pretenses.

Comment: North Korea has "elections" where the only candidates are pawns of Kim Jong-Un, as an example. Similar idea in Cuba and other places that try to appear democratic to their citizens.

Comment: Want to filter out illiterates? Use a [literacy test](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Literacy_test)!

Comment: That's perfect @PatriciaShanahan, If I have the right to create a filter, why not create a filter in favor of my ideas? In a true democracy, we should allow everyone. I was thinking about filtering only by beneficence, for example, excluding illiterates, ex-criminals, requiring some type of study degree e.g allowing one that could create true value for society. But again, what is valuable for you, is not valuable for me. Filtering may not be a good idea at all.

Comment: @user253751 but in this case, they should be represented by social programs, not an actual illiterate, right? If not, drug addicts should be represented by a drug addict as well, which sounds not very beneficial

Comment: @renanAlmeida828 I don't understand. How can a social program sit in a seat in parliament?

Comment: *"in Brazil we can elect people with any criminal history/records"* Not really, at least after the "clean record" law, which asserts that people sentenced for crimes judged on second appeal court lose their political rights. Although, you might be a notorious serial killer and run for office during the appeal process at the second court or before.

Comment: @user253751 : He probably meant that a bulk of illiterate people would likely prefer someone of humble origins (and likely illiterate as well) to take a seat on parliament and represent them. Now this people should be taken care of by social programs indeed, but they also have a right to vote and prefer someone who knows "for real" what is like to be like them. That being said, political candidates are required to claim to be literate, and Tiririca had claimed to have achieved *"incomplete primary education"*, which still ranks higher than the option *"can read and write"*

Comment: There are many pieces of wrong information in the question, so just to set the record straight: (1) candidates must not have previous convictions (as mentioned by @Mefitico); (2) joke candidates are common, but it's actually very rare for them to get elected; (3) the minimum age is 18 only for _vereadores_ (city ​​councilors). All other positions require greater ages.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

While in centuries past, being openly opposed to democracy was well within the Overton window, these days it is generally not seen as acceptable. Most dictatorships at least pretend to be democratic; even North Korea styles itself the "Democratic People's Republic of Korea". However, each election has only one candidate, chosen by the Democratic Front for the Reunification of the Fatherland. This is the general pattern for Communist countries: lip service to democracy, but in practice no real choice.

In Iran, all candidates must be approved by the Guardian Council (and be men). While the Guardian Council gave Iranians more choice than North Koreans got, with six candidates approved for the 2107 presidential election, it was still a highly restricted field.

In Russia, candidates must fulfill official restrictions, such as being a citizen of the Russian Federation who is at least 35 years old and has "permanently resided" in Russia for at least 10 years, and be nominated by a faction of the State Duma or receive 100,000 signatures (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/President_of_Russia). There are also unofficial requirements, such as not having unfortunate encounters with polonium.

In the US, there are a variety of restrictions, depending on the position. The president must be at least 35 years old and be a "natural born citizen", which is generally interpreted as meaning  a citizen at birth (strangely, many people brought this up as an issue with regard to Obama's candidacy, despite him having a Hawaii birth certificate, but there was little argument that McCain, born in the Panama Canal Zone, was not eligible). Some states, such as Florida, have restrictions on felons running for office. There are also some states that have restrictions on atheists running for office, but those are not enforced and would certainly be held unconstitutional if they were.

This is just a small sampling of the restrictions around the world; with hundreds of countries, it would be a rather large task to catalog them all.

Comment: I was thinking about filtering only by beneficence, for example, excluding illiterates, ex-criminals, requiring some type of study degree. But as you and @PatriciaShanahan mentioned, who creates the rules... rules. 

Thank you for your answer, clarified a lot!

Comment: @renanAlmeida828 Presumably, the filters are justified on the basis of alleged beneficence. Not being a communist/Muslim/what have you is evidence of moral degeneracy.